# Php echo date,month,day,hour,minute,second in numbers only

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a PHP command to echo current timestamp in numbers.
Example: 25/02/2015 and time 10:40:31 should be output like: 25022015104031

Comment: Use `strtotime()` in php. it will convert your date into number.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("d").date("m").date("Y").date("H").date("i").date("s");
```

or the short version

```
echo date('dmYHis');
```

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Understand how not to do it maybe.

Comment: Yeah, missed that one, srry

Comment: I don't see any errors `.` just concatenates strings in PHP.

Comment: @Ties I edited my answer, it was a "," instead "." here "date("i").date("s")"

Comment: @MarinescuAdrian that should actually work too. `echo` accepts multiple parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the php date documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you see that there are sufficient ways to display a date (and time) in a human-readable format.

In your example the following code will do fine:

```
echo date('dmYHis');
```

```
format: description:                                            example:

d:      Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros           01 to 31
m:      Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
Y:      A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits       1999 or 2003
H:      24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros            00 through 23
i:      Minutes with leading zeros                              00 to 59
s:      Seconds, with leading zeros                             00 through 59
```

Check the documentation for more ways of displaying date formats.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
echo date('dmYHis');
```

Human readable way:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Worked fine for date, but not for time.. It doesnt display time in a 'human-readable' format

Comment: `G` (hours without leading zero) and `H` (hours with leading zero) both show hours so you have duplicate information.

Comment: @JohnGreco I added a human readable way. Thanks Ties, just saw it. A little bit to quick with my first answer :).